# Write html tags to text file in python

Tags: python, io, pdftotext, pdfminer, pdf-to-html

I've used pdfminer to convert complex (tables, figures) and very long pdfs to html. I want to parse the results further (e.g. extract tables, paragraphs etc) and then use sentence tokenizer from nltk to do further analysis. For this purposes I want to save the html to text file to figure out how to do the parsing. Unfortunately my code does not write html to txt:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import HTMLConverter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO


def convert_pdf_to_html(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = HTMLConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0 #is for all
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str1 = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str1
    with open("D:/my_new_file.txt", "wb") as fh:
        fh.write(str1)
```

Besides, the code prints the whole html string in the shell: how can I avoid it?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Thank you! You are right, now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, unless there's a trivial error,

the .txt write happens after the return function: txt file write is never executed!

Then, to suppress output to the console, just do that before running your routine:

```
 import sys,os
 oldstdout = sys.stdout  # save to be able to restore it later
 sys.stdout = os.devnull
```